# "multiple definition of 'SomeFuction'". No idea how to fix

Tags: c++, arduino, include, arduino-c++, teensy

I'm writing an Arduino app (Using platformIO in VSCode), and including an external CAN library (FlexCAN_T4). I want to define all of my protocol / message handler callbacks in a separate file (protocol.cpp), and refer to them from my main file (main.cpp). So I create a header file (protocol.h) with all my function signatures, and include protocol.h from both protocol.cpp and main.cpp.

But I'm getting "multiple definition of `flexcan_isr_can1()'" (which is a function defined in a referenced library, FlexCAN_T4). I can't figure out how to get rid of this error, and still have all my function signatures and constants and whatnot work properly.

Sample error messages (one for each non-class function defined in FlexCan_T4.h):

```
.pio/build/teensy40/src/protocol.cpp.o: In function `flexcan_isr_can1()':
protocol.cpp:(.text._Z16flexcan_isr_can1v+0x0): multiple definition of `flexcan_isr_can1()'
.pio/build/teensy40/src/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text._Z16flexcan_isr_can1v+0x0): first defined here
/Users/pdesrosiers/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/5.4.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: Disabling relaxation: it will not work with multiple definitions
```

*protocol.h*

```
#pragma once
#include <FlexCAN_T4.h>
const uint8_t myConst = 100;
extern FlexCAN_T4<CAN1, RX_SIZE_256, TX_SIZE_16> flexCAN;

void myFunction();
```

*protocol.cpp*

```
#include "protocol.h"
FlexCAN_T4<CAN1, RX_SIZE_256, TX_SIZE_16> flexCAN;

void myFunction()
{
    //one of a hundred functions related to protocol, that should be defined outside of main.cpp.
    flexCan.doSomething(myConst);
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "protocol.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup()
{
  //some setup stuff...
}

void loop()
{
  myFunction();
}
```

In a certain sense, these errors make sense, since protocol.h (and, transitively, FlexCAN_T4.h) is being #included multiple times.

But how can I keep this nice organization of code, which my callbacks defined outside main.cpp? What's the correct way to include these dependencies?

Comment: The Arduino language is C++ minus some features, not C. The problem is that the header file `<FlexCAN_T4.h>` has a function **definition** but it doesn't have `#pragma once`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Since FlexCAN_T4.h is only included transitively, via protocol.h, and protocol.h has #pragma once, shouldn't that be enough? (though I admit, #pragma once has mystified me on more than one occasion, as it never seems to do what I think it will).

Answer (score 0):

If FlexCAN_T4 related parts are not necessary in protocol.h, you may put them in cpp file. 
Such as removing the following part and put them to protocol.cpp:

## include

extern FlexCAN_T4 flexCAN;

Comment: #include <FlexCAN_T4.h>
extern FlexCAN_T4<CAN1, RX_SIZE_256, TX_SIZE_16> flexCAN;

Comment: The code I pasted is simplified to illustrate a minimal repro. In reality, there are a ton f function definitions in protocol.h, that need FlexCAN_T4 for their parameters unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `flexcan_isr_can1` (and other functions) is defined in a header file that gets included into multiple translation units.  This is a violation of the One Definition Rule.  The [relevant](https://github.com/tonton81/FlexCAN_T4/blob/master/FlexCAN_T4.tpp#L866-L876) function definitions should have the `inline` keyword added to them.

---

This is a defect in the FlexCAN_T4 library; you should submit the issue to the library's maintainer.

Comment: I am the author of the library and it is still in development for functionality of the hardware. The hardware just came out recently so things are still in process.. thanks

Comment: Since' FlexCAN_T4.h is only included transitively, via protocol.h, which is "protected" by #pragma once, shouldn't that stop a multi-include?

Comment: @roach374 No. `#pragma once` or equivalent include guards stop a header from being included more than once in _the same translation unit_.  The issue here is that FlexCAN_T4.h is included in multiple translation units (protocol.cpp and main.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

I already have include guards, which are more recommended than #pragma once, and was always in the H file:

```
#if !defined(_FLEXCAN_T4_H_)
#define _FLEXCAN_T4_H_
```

Where is the defect you claim to be seeing?